# Collectionviewsource Datagrid WPF MVVM Not showing rows

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I'm new to WPF and MVVM. I'm trying to use a Datagrid along with a Collectionviewsource in my project. I have worked up to some level as below, but my Datagrid is not showing any rows. Below is the code parts. I'm trying to figure what I am missing here. Note that I am only publishing the code parts which are necessary to this problem. [image]

**ScanBatchWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ScanBatchWindow : Window
{
    public ScanBatchWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ScanBatchViewModel pMV = new ScanBatchViewModel();
        this.DataContext = pMV;
    }
}
```

**ScanBatchWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="BatchManPOC.ScanBatchWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BatchManPOC"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:cmdBehavior="clr-namespace:BatchManPOC.CmdBehavior"
    xmlns:video="clr-namespace:BatchManPOC.Video"
    xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ScanBatchWindow" 
    Height="800"
    Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding p_ListBatches}" x:Key="CVS"/>
</Window.Resources>
     <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Custom:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVS}}" Margin="8" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  IsReadOnly="True">
</Custom:DataGrid>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ScanBatchViewModel.cs**

Note that I have a **BaseViewModel** which inherit from **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

```
    public class ScanBatchViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public CollectionViewSource CVS { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Batch> p_ListBatches { get; set; }

        public class Batch
        {
            public DateTime p_dCreated;
            public int p_iReference;
            public BatchStatus p_iBatchStatus;
            public string p_sFromBranch;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ScanBatchViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public ScanBatchViewModel()
        {
            LoadBatches();
            CVS = new CollectionViewSource();
        }

        public void LoadBatches()
        {
            //Add sample objects
            p_ListBatches.Add(new Batch() { p_dCreated = DateTime.Now, p_iBatchStatus = BatchStatus.DOC_STATUS_CREATED, p_iReference = 1, p_sFromBranch = "7010888" });
            p_ListBatches.Add(new Batch() { p_dCreated = DateTime.Now, p_iBatchStatus = BatchStatus.DOC_STATUS_DELETED, p_iReference = 2, p_sFromBranch = "7010999" });
            p_ListBatches.Add(new Batch() { p_dCreated = DateTime.Now, p_iBatchStatus = BatchStatus.DOC_STATUS_RECEIVED, p_iReference = 3, p_sFromBranch = "7010000" });
            p_ListBatches.Add(new Batch() { p_dCreated = DateTime.Now, p_iBatchStatus = BatchStatus.DOC_STATUS_SENT, p_iReference = 4, p_sFromBranch = "7010777" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: please look for errors in Output window. There might be some binding issue

Comment: @ASh Thanks and just saw your comments. Yes, the cause was related to property binding. I was looking for this answer but could not find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found the answer. I have not defined members of the **Batch** class as **properties**. Therefore, although we set the values to public members, they will not appear in the .XAML since they are not exposed as properties. Changing them as below worked for me. [image]

```
public class Batch
{
    public DateTime p_dCreated { get; set; }
    public int p_iReference { get; set; }
    public BatchStatus p_iBatchStatus { get; set; }
    public string p_sFromBranch { get; set; }
}
```